# Apache - htaccess - Site appears to be using another sites htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a magento site setup and another separate site on the same server, the second site seems to be using the magento site's .htaccess rules though.

I've looked in the configs in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ where I assume the issue is but I'm not exactly sure what I am looking for.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

any .htaccess file applies not only to the directory whithin which it is located but also to the directory structure below it. so the second site may be affected a .htaccess file somewhere above it.